# convert string to date with locale

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to convert a string to date but every time i do it keeps throwing errors at me, Im not sure what i am missing

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        // m brings in all variables from a get/setter
        date = format.parse(m.getEventTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Response.Error.Date", m.getEventTime());
    }
    eventTime.setText(date.toString());
```

My variable m.getEventTime() is passing the following string `2018-04-28 14:00:00`

I have tried passing the string as `2018-04-28T14:00:00Z` to no avail.

No errors are coming from the stack trace from the try/catch block but the log is printing out `D/Response.Error.Date: 2017-08-19 15:00:00`
when i add e.toString() to the log it prints out `D/Response.Error.Date: 2017-08-19 15:00:00 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-08-19 15:00:00"`

On the actual application when run the time is shown as `now` Sat Apr 28 08:22:33 GMT+01:00 2018

Am i missing something?

Comment: The simple date format should me "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" to parse that string

Comment: @JyotiJK Thanks, i thought `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yy hh:mm a"` was how to parse - changing to your way allowed me to actually parse the date - but now how would i change it to the `EEE, MMM d, yy hh:mm a` format?

Comment: after getting date, again change the date to this format `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);`. And the result will be in string not date.

Comment: A `Date` doesn’t have a format, so to obtain your desired format you need to format it into a new string using a new formatter. As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I would consider it quite a serious problem that you cannot see a stacktrace being printed. You should look into fixing your project setup so you can see what your program is trying to tell you about errors that have occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat oldformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    // m brings in all variables from a get/setter
    date = oldformat.parse(m.getEventTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("Response.Error.Date", m.getEventTime());
}
eventTime.setText(format.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get time format like this:

```
    String dateTime = null;

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm a");
                              //here you can use your required format 

    dateTime = df.format(new Date(stringTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting date into English which is causing the exception:

Please Change:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

eventTime.setText(date.toString());
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yy hh:mm a");

eventTime.setText(format.format(date));
```

Comment: Incorrect answer, sorry. With your change the same exception is still thrown.

Comment: Sorry! Please change "eventTime.setText(date.toString());" to "eventTime.setText(format.format(date));" too.

Comment: Prakhar Gupta, if you think you have an answer to the reason for the `ParseException`, you may [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50074700/edit). This is better than adding information in a comment.